# usages of although and having past participle

Tags: prepositions, verbs, conjunctions

would you possibly show me if I have grammatically or properly rephrased the sentence above? if no, could you please correct me?

Having remained a mystery until today, however, Maya hieroglyphs are really a bible for modern man,

***ANSWER:***

I'd say you'd need:

Although having remained a mystery until today, Maya hieroglyphs are really a bible for modern man.

as you have to stress the subordinate with the reservation, not the main.

---

Teachers Matter: Connecting Work, Lives And Effectiveness - Page 74
Day, Christopher, ‎Sammons, Pam, ‎Stobart, Gordon - 2007

Although having remained highly committed to the school and to the students, Darius's level of motivation had decreased.

....

***My*** specific ***question***: as you see one of my friend has answered me above. But, I have never seen such a usage of having or although. Could anyone please show me a grammar source or how does it work?

***Although having remained*** a mystery until today, Maya hieroglyphs are really a bible for modern man.

Any help would greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although + having + past participle

It's not grammatically correct to use the conjunction "although" in this manner. We use "although" with a finite verb (the verb that shows the tense and the subject).
However, if you replace "although" with "despite", it will work here.

So, it's wrong to say "Although having remained a mystery today, Maya hieroglyphs are really a bible for modern man". The correct sentence should be as follows:

"Although Maya hieroglyphs have remained a mystery today, they are really a bible for modern man". (See use of although - British Council).